# How to arrange elements in the list

Tags: coq

I am arranging natural numbers in a specific order in the list. My defined function finds the greatest element(n0) in the list. Now I want to prove that all the elements in the list,are less or equal, to n0. I have a problem in proving a lemma. I want to prove the following lemma

```
Theorem values_les_than_n :forall(n0 n1:nat) ( l:list nat),    
        (g_value (length (n1 :: l))    
        (change n0 (n1 :: l)) <=? n0) = true
   
     Definition change (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat :=  
       match l with  
       | nil => l  
       | h::tl => if n <=? h then l else n::tl  end.
        Fixpoint g_value (elements: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=       
        match l with       
         | nil => 0       
         | [n] => n       
         | h :: l => match elements with       
         | O => h       
         | S elements' => g_value elements' (change h l)
          end     
         end.
Lemma ni_con:forall(x:A)(l:list A),[]<>x::l.
Proof.
simpl.  discriminate. 
Qed.
Definition listvalue (n:nat)(l : list nat) : In (g_value n l) l -> nat.
intros.
apply : g_value (n l).
Defined.

Lemma value_in_input s l : 
  l = nil \/ In (g_value s l) l.
Proof.
intros.
left. 
assert(forall(x:A)(l:list A),[]<>x::l).
{ apply ni_con. }
simpl. auto . discriminate. 
right. unfold g_value. 
Admitted.

 Fixpoint In (a:nat) (l:list nat) : Prop :=
  match l with
  | nil => False
  | b :: m => b = a \/ In a m
  end.

   Fixpoint firstn {A} (x : nat) (ls : list A) : list A := 
    match x with
       |S n' => match ls with
             |h :: t => h::firstn n' t
             |[] => []
            end
      |0 => []
      end.

       Lemma value_greater s l n : In n (firstn s l) -> n <= g_value s l.
       Proof.
        induction 1. intros k H'.
      now exfalso; apply in_nil in H'. 
       Admitted.
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem? What would like to do and don't know how to?

Comment: The coq example is not self contained.  You need to add the following first lines `Require Import List Arith.  Import ListNotations. Definition Servers := list nat.`

Answer (score 1):

This theorem cannot be true: `n` is completely independent from `n0`, `n1`, or `servers`.  The value returned by the `g_value` expression (in your theorem statement) can only be taken among `n0` `n1` and `servers`, it is not hard to make sure the values are not the same.  Here is an example: if you were able to prove the theorem, there would be a contradiction.

```
Require Import List Arith.

Import ListNotations.

Definition Servers := list nat.

Definition change (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat :=  
   match l with  
   | nil => l  
   | h::tl => if n <=? h then l else n::tl  end.

Fixpoint g_value (elements: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=       
    match l with       
     | nil => 0       
     | [n] => n       
     | h :: l => match elements with       
     | O => h       
     | S elements' => g_value elements' (change h l)
      end     
     end.

Theorem values_les_than_n :forall(n n0 n1:nat) ( servers:Servers),    
    (g_value (length (n1 :: servers))    
    (change n0 (n1 :: servers)) <=? n) = true.
Admitted.

Lemma contradict_it : False.
  assert (tmp := values_les_than_n 0 1 1 nil).   
  discriminate tmp.
Qed.
```

You should often test your functions before attempting proofs.

Comment: With this line, the following "Admitted.", and the subsequent proof, we show that the theorem you want to prove cannot hold, it would lead to a contradiction.  Does it help?

Comment: Oh, it is very difficult to notice the difference.

Comment: Nope, your new statement is not provable either.  The function `change` only performs tests at the beginning of the list, but what is in `l` is not related to the beginning of the list in any way, it can be arbitrary.  The function `g_value`, when applied to the list length, returns the last element of the list, so again, the value in the end of the list is completely independent from `n` and `n1`  and it is not difficult to produce a counter example.  If your new theorem is applied to `n=0` `n1=1` and `l = 2::nil` , then the conclusion of the theorem computes to `false = true`, not good!

Comment: The statement you just expressed in English is not what you wrote as a logical statement.   In the new statement, there is nothing that says `n` is the greatest element of the input list.

Comment: No, you have to make it a different question, I will answer only if it is a new stack-exchange question.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a new answer because the comments on the previous answer make it possible to clarify the initial intent.

In the initial question, the author wishes to show that `g_value (length l) l` always returns the greatest element of `l` or `0` if `l` is empty.  However, in the statement that is proposed in the initial question, or in the statement proposed later in the comments, there is no constraint on `n`.

So you should simply write the following two lemmas:

```
Lemma value_in_input s l : l = nil \/ In (g_value s l) l.

Lemma value_greater s l n : In n (firstn s l) -> n <= g_value s l.
```

I had time to check that both statements are provable.

The function `firstn` is provided in the Coq standard library, and it is recursive on its two inputs.  An analysis of `g_value` (and the feedback message from Coq) tells us that `g_value` is recursive on its first argument, this suggests that `value_greater` should be proved by induction on `n`.

Here is an example of how this proof can be done:

```
Lemma value_greater s l n : In n (firstn s l) -> n <= g_value s l.
Proof.
revert l n; induction s as [ | s IH].
  destruct l as [ | n1 l]; contradiction.
destruct l as [ | n1 [ | n2 l]]; try contradiction.
  simpl; intros n [nn1 | abs].
    now rewrite nn1; auto with arith.
  destruct s; simpl in abs; contradiction.
intros n inn.
simpl.
destruct (n1 <=? n2) eqn:cmp.
  simpl in inn.
  destruct inn as [n1_is_n | inn'].
    apply le_trans with n2.
      rewrite <- Nat.leb_le.
      rewrite <- n1_is_n.
      exact cmp.
    destruct s as [ | s'].
      simpl.
      destruct l.
        apply le_n.
      now apply le_n.
    apply IH.
    simpl.
    now auto.
  apply IH. 
  exact inn'.
assert (n1le : n1 <= g_value s (n1 :: l)).
  destruct s as [ | s'].
     simpl.
   destruct l.
      apply le_n.
    apply le_n.
  apply IH.
  simpl.
  now auto.
simpl in inn.
destruct inn as [n1_is_n | other].
  rewrite <- n1_is_n.
  assumption.
destruct s as [ | s'].    
  simpl in other.
  now destruct other.
simpl in other.
destruct other as [n2_is_n | other'].
  rewrite <- n2_is_n.
  apply le_trans with n1.
    apply Nat.lt_le_incl.
    rewrite <- Nat.leb_gt.
    exact cmp.
  exact n1le.
apply IH.
simpl.
right.
exact other'.
Qed.
```

This proof is long and complicated, but it feels to me that you have some responsibility for that, because the code of `g_value` and `change` are overly complicated for the purpose at hand.

Your attempt for a proof of induction goes in the wrong direction because, you let `s` be fixed during the induction proof, but in recursive calls to `g_value` and `firstn`, `s` decreases.  If `s` is fixed, the induction hypotheses cannot be used to reason about the recursive calls.

Comment: (firstn s l) is function ,which takes s l as input argument,and gives a list as output , after finding element which is equal to n?

Comment: `firstn` returns the first n elements of a list

Comment: @ Yves.I have defined firstn function and modified the code also(this is what I have tried).Now how to solve the lemma?

Comment: Hello, rosi javi, I edited my second answer to reply to you modification.  Please change your way of asking questions, this makes that our conversation is completely impossible to follow for other readers.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit my question and try to follow it next time.

Comment: First lemma can be close,if we prove left or right side of the (or) operator.Left side of the lemma is (l=nil) ,I have defined empty list and its prove ,then why it does not works here?

Comment: Your statement `values_eq_0` is obscure: you quantify over a variable `n`, but this variable is never used.

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question in your last comment in a comment.  Please open a new question, and I will post an answer there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to reach me by mail.

Comment: mailing Id? Actually definitation is same ,question is different.When I will post  question,I have to write definitation first ,to explain the question.In this case ,similiarity errors arises.

Comment: In hypothesis, I have  (g_value (length (n1 ::n2:: l)) (change n0 (n1 ::n2:: l)) =? 0) = true & want to prove that (n2=?0)=true. Hypothesis says that ,all elements in the list are zero.At index 2 of the list ,element is zero simililarly at S(index 2) value is also zero.

Comment: I don't want to write my name here, but there aren't that many people with first name Yves that are active in the Coq community.  You will find my name and my web-page through an internet search.