# Greatest value in natural number list

Tags: coq

I have defined a function,which finds greatest value in the list of natural numbers and head  of the list save this value. I want to prove that all the elements in the list are less or equal to natural number present at head of the list.I have problem in proving the lemma. I have written two lemmas,I want to know,which would be helpful in solving the problem. Thanks for help and
support .

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

  Definition change_variable (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat:=
   match l with
   | nil => l
   | h::t => if n <=? h then l else n::t
   end.

 Fixpoint largest_value (numbers: nat) (l: list nat) {struct numbers}: nat:= 
 match l with
 | nil => 0
 | cons b nil => b 
 | cons h l => match numbers with
 | O => h
 | S numbers' => largest_value numbers' (change_variable h l)
  end
  end.

Theorem all_values_less :forall (n c :nat)(l:list nat),
(largest_value (length (c :: l))
 (change_variable n (c :: l)) <= n). 

    First in this way,
       Inductive changing : l -> Prop :=
        | change_nil : changing nil
        | change_1 n : changing (cons n nil)
        | change_head n h l :
         n <= h ->
        changing (cons h l) ->
      changing (cons n l).

  Lemma head_is_gt l a:
   changing  l -> forall n, In n l -> n <= hd a l.
      Proof.
      induction 1. intros k H'.
      now exfalso; apply in_nil in H'. 
      Admitted.
    
    Secondly ,
    Definition head_is_greater (l: list nat): nil <> l -> nat.
    intros.
    destruct l.
    destruct (H (@erefl (list nat) nil)).
     apply : (largest_value s l).
    
     Defined. 
     Theorem values_les_n : forall l (H : [] <> l) n, In n l -> n <= 
      head_is_greater H.
```

Comment: I am not eligible to mark this question as a duplicate, but the similarity with https://stackoverflow.com/a/62889505/1809211 is striking.   Both question askers have a trouble writing the formal statement that expresses correctly the objective as stated in English.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem does not hold, unfortunately.  Here is a counterexample:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Lia.
Import ListNotations.

Definition change_variable (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat:=
   match l with
   | nil => l
   | h::t => if n <=? h then l else n::t
   end.

 Fixpoint largest_value (numbers: nat) (l: list nat) {struct numbers}: nat:=
 match l with
 | nil => 0
 | cons b nil => b
 | cons h l => match numbers with
 | O => h
 | S numbers' => largest_value numbers' (change_variable h l)
  end
  end.

Hypothesis all_values_less :forall (n c :nat)(l:list nat),
(largest_value (length (c :: l))
 (change_variable n (c :: l)) <= n).

Theorem contra : False.
Proof.
pose proof (all_values_less 0 1 []).
simpl in *. lia.
Qed.
```

You probably need to add more hypothesis to your statement to rule out such cases.

Comment: Yes ,there is similiarity.I have read your's  answer.You suggested the addition of two lemans.How these lemmas could be helpful? What is the meaning of  (firstn s l) in lemma? You have talked about constraints on n,I have n at head position and it is nat,which is not zero.How we can prove second lemma, with mimimum hypothesises?@Yves

Comment: The point is that you wrote the sentence "I want to prove that all elements of ..."  What you say in English is correct, but one you wrote as a statement in Coq simply does not say the same thing.  the lemmas I proposed in the other answer are the Coq statements that say what you want.   I checked they were provable, but I don't want to give the solution to what seems to be an exercise given by a professor.

Comment: @Yves.I have modified the question,to prove lemma ,how I should proceed?Exercise /assignment time is over.(month have been passed).Plz help me in closing the goal.Thank you